# SMSlib compilation issues

Tags: java, ant, smslib

I'm trying to build the SMSLib master source from [here](https://github.com/smslib/smslib-v3). As per installation instructions, I have copied the following jar files into \lib\ext folders of jre.

```
comm.jar
commons-net-3.3.jar
jsmpp-2.1.0.jar
```

I have copied the win32com.dll to \jre\bin. I have also put javax.comm.properties \jre\lib directory. When i try to compile the source using ANT. It shows lot of errors within smslib source itself

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Keerthi\Downloads\smslib-v3-master\build.xml

compile.smslib:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Keerthi\Downloads\smslib-v3-master\dist\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] C:\Users\Keerthi\Downloads\smslib-v3-master\src\java\org\smslib\smpp\jsmpp\JSMPPGateway.java:282: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]         @Override
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Keerthi\Downloads\smslib-v3-master\src\java\org\smslib\smpp\jsmpp\JSMPPGateway.java:302: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 encoding = Alphabet.ALPHA_UNSPECIFIED_2;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable ALPHA_UNSPECIFIED_2
    [javac]   location: class Alphabet
    [javac] C:\Users\Keerthi\Downloads\smslib-v3-master\src\java\org\smslib\smpp\jsmpp\JSMPPGateway.java:309: error: no suitable constructor found for GeneralDataCoding(Alphabet,MessageClass,boolean)
    [javac]                 dataCoding = new GeneralDataCoding(encoding, MessageClass.CLASS0, true);
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(boolean,boolean,MessageClass,Alphabet) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(int) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(byte) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac] C:\Users\Keerthi\Downloads\smslib-v3-master\src\java\org\smslib\smpp\jsmpp\JSMPPGateway.java:312: error: no suitable constructor found for GeneralDataCoding(Alphabet,MessageClass,boolean)
    [javac]                 dataCoding = new GeneralDataCoding(encoding, MessageClass.CLASS1, true);
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(boolean,boolean,MessageClass,Alphabet) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(int) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(byte) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac] C:\Users\Keerthi\Downloads\smslib-v3-master\src\java\org\smslib\smpp\jsmpp\JSMPPGateway.java:315: error: no suitable constructor found for GeneralDataCoding(Alphabet,MessageClass,boolean)
    [javac]                 dataCoding = new GeneralDataCoding(encoding, MessageClass.CLASS2, true);
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(boolean,boolean,MessageClass,Alphabet) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(int) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(byte) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac] C:\Users\Keerthi\Downloads\smslib-v3-master\src\java\org\smslib\smpp\jsmpp\JSMPPGateway.java:318: error: no suitable constructor found for GeneralDataCoding(Alphabet,MessageClass,boolean)
    [javac]                 dataCoding = new GeneralDataCoding(encoding, MessageClass.CLASS3, true);
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(boolean,boolean,MessageClass,Alphabet) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(int) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(byte) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac] C:\Users\Keerthi\Downloads\smslib-v3-master\src\java\org\smslib\smpp\jsmpp\JSMPPGateway.java:321: error: no suitable constructor found for GeneralDataCoding(Alphabet,MessageClass,boolean)
    [javac]                 dataCoding = new GeneralDataCoding(encoding, MessageClass.CLASS1, true);
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(boolean,boolean,MessageClass,Alphabet) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(int) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding(byte) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor GeneralDataCoding.GeneralDataCoding() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac] 7 errors
    [javac] 1 warning
```

Please help me figure out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSMPP` jar version was the problem. Once I updated it to v2.2.1. It worked like a charm.

Note: When you build the source from github, you don't have to copy the above mentioned jar file into \lib\ext directories. These jars are already present in the lib directory of the source.